# How to remove text polygons from filltext() in Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

The following draws text into a canvas image, into a top line and a bottom line. The issue is that `stroketext()` make weird polygon shapes come out of the text. Both `filltext()` and `stroketext()` need to be use so that the text can be white with a black border, which will be visible on any image irrespective of its background colour. Is there any way to remove the polygons?

```
drawText = function(context, pos, text) {
    var fontSize = 100;
    while(1) {
        context.font = "bold " + fontSize + "px Arial";
        if( (context.measureText(text).width < (width-15)) && (fontSize < height/10) ) {
            break;
        }
        fontSize-=2;
    }

    var y;
    if(pos == "top")
        y = fontSize + 15;
    else if(pos == "bottom") {
        y = height - 15;
    }

    context.strokeText(text, width/2, y);
    context.fillText(text, width/2, y); 
}

updateList = function(doc, where) {
    if(where == "top")
        $("#list").prepend(makeCanvas(doc));
    else {
        $("#list").append(makeCanvas(doc));
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById(doc._id);
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.strokeStyle = "#000";
    context.lineWidth = 6;

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = getTemplateLink(doc.name);
    img.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawText(context, "top", doc.text.line1);
        drawText(context, "bottom", doc.text.line2);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling only `fillText()` doesn't show the "weird polygon shapes" but adding a call to `strokeText()` does? Are the characters in the `text` string all present in the "Arial _px Bold" font - i.e., are there embedded newline or tab or other characters for which Arial would normally show a box? Obviously I haven't tried your code, but these are questions I came up with to perhaps help a bit.

Comment: Correct about the weird shapes only with stroketext(). No additional characters are embedded.